# MySql Error(UBUNTU):The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, lamp

Hi when i enter:GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
I get:The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement.
What should i do to off skip-grant-tables option?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check mysql configs in `/etc/mysql/` or the runscript in `/etc/init.d/` .

---

Edit:
Try this: GRANT ALL, GRANT OPTION ON *.* TO user@localhost;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: What should I check?

Comment: Oh sorry the vm have been fixed now. Will report soon.